# Erro ao executar script em Python3 (com Symfony/Process) em um Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, python-3.x, symfony

Estou tentando executar um script em Python3 que desenvolvi, que está localizado em uma pasta dentro do "app folder" do Laravel. Um dos script é chamado por um Controller e o outro por um Artisan Command.

```
public static function searchAnswers($input)
    {
        $process = new Process(array('dir', base_path() . '/app/SearchEngine'));
        $process->setWorkingDirectory(base_path() . '/app/SearchEngine');
        $process->setCommandLine('python3 SearchEngine.py ' . '"'. $input .'"');
        $process->setTimeout(2 * 3600);

        $process->run();  

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {            //Executes after the command finishes
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }

        $list_ids = array_map('intval', explode(' ', $process->getOutput()));
        info($list_ids);
        $solicitations = Solicitation::join('answers', 'solicitations.id', '=', 'answers.solicitation_id')
                            ->whereIn('solicitations.id', $list_ids)
                            ->limit(20)
                            ->get();
        info($solicitations);
        return $solicitations;
    }
```

No meu ambiente localhost, toda a integração funciona perfeitamente. Mas, depois que subi minha aplicação pro meu servidor remoto (Debian), estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
"""
The command "python3 SearchEngine.py "O que é fogo no **?"" failed.\n
\n
Exit Code: 1(General error)\n
\n
Working directory: /var/www/plataformaTS/app/SearchEngine\n
\n
Output:\n
================\n
\n
\n
Error Output:\n
================\n
Traceback (most recent call last):\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 80, in __load\n
    try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 675, in find\n
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)\n
LookupError: \n
**********************************************************************\n
  Resource \e[93mstopwords\e[0m not found.\n
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n
\n
  \e[31m>>> import nltk\n
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')\n
  \e[0m\n
  Searched in:\n
    - '/var/www/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'\n
**********************************************************************\n
\n
\n
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n
\n
Traceback (most recent call last):\n
  File "SearchEngine.py", line 20, in <module>\n
    stopwords = stopwords.words('portuguese')\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 116, in __getattr__\n
    self.__load()\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 81, in __load\n
    except LookupError: raise e\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/util.py", line 78, in __load\n
    root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, self.__name))\n
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/data.py", line 675, in find\n
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)\n
LookupError: \n
**********************************************************************\n
  Resource \e[93mstopwords\e[0m not found.\n
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:\n
\n
  \e[31m>>> import nltk\n
  >>> nltk.download('stopwords')\n
  \e[0m\n
  Searched in:\n
    - '/var/www/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'\n
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'\n
**********************************************************************\n
\n
"""
```

Só que, quando eu executo o script direto no meu terminal, os resultados estão vindo como esperado. Então, o erro não está relacionada a instalação das libs no meu servidor. O script que é chamado pelo php artisan :command também funciona perfeitamente.

O que pode estar acontecendo? É alguma configuração do servidor?

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro parece sim, estar relacionado à instalação de libs no servidor.

Dê uma olhada [nesta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26693897/1284458), aparentemente a lib `nltk` não achou o recurso `stopwords` e lançou o erro.

Segundo o link acima, uma solução seria abrir o python no console do seu servidor e rodar o comando:

```
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")
```

Ou, como mencionado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048876/1284458):

```
python -m nltk.downloader stopwords
```

Apenas tome cuidado para não executar `download` sem parâmetros, senão você vai fazer download de muita coisa que talvez não precise.